# Difference-in-difference more than two periods

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis

I try to use a difference-in-difference design in my study. But I have three periods. So I would like to know how I could run my difference-in-difference analysis on Stata with more than two periods.

Comment: This question seems to be *only* about how to do this in Stata. Thus, it would be off-topic for CV (see our [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). Statalist may be an appropriate option. If you have a question about the statistical issues involved here, please edit to clarify; otherwise, this question may be closed.

Comment: Even on Statalist, where I am active, we expect a bit more effort (e.g. > 0) than is evident here. Otherwise "please tell me the code I need" is always a fair question, and in practice it isn't. However, there is a statistical question hidden here, which is what is the equivalent of difference-in-difference design for three periods. My own wild guess is that is not difference-in-difference. So, I think there is some scope for rewriting this as an interesting statistical question, but it can't be acceptably phrased as what Stata code do I need.

Comment: @NickCox, I thought the same thing, but it's also not clear that the OP recognizes the statistical question or is interested in it. I was hoping the comment would prompt some further development.

Answer (score 1):

You can just run a regression with dummies for group, the treatment period, and their interaction. The diff-in-diff is the coefficient on the interaction:

```
regress y i.time_dummy##i.group_dummy controlvars
xtreg y i.time_dummy##i.group_dummy controlvars, fe
```

The first would work nicely if you have repeated cross sections. The second is for a true panel.